# Set ivi-shell as default in core-image-weston

Tags: yocto

Can someone tell me if and how it is possible to activate the ivi shell as default shell in core-image-weston ?

Regards

Comment: Are you using `weston wayland` or `x11` ?

Comment: weston/wayland. I have an application that uses weston/wayland/EGL/OpenGL. The application also needs an ivi-application component. I want to start the ivi-shell in a way so I still have a command prompt where I can start the application if possible.

Comment: I think `meta-ivi` has a custom `weston.ini` file appended to `weston-init` recipe containing ivi shell setup.

Comment: I'm stumped. I changed the shell entry to "ivi-shell.so" in weston.ini, but when I start the qemu I see nothing. In the regular wayland shell all the glxgears etc. work, but not in the ivi shell.